# Textured Sky in Orthographic Mode

Tags: orthographic

I was hoping that there might be a way to make a textured sky while in the camera's orthographic mode? I am making a pre-rendered 2.5D platforming game, and it would save me a lot of trouble if I could find a way to do this. It's easy to use Dynamic Skies in perspective mode, but as you know, as soon as I go to orthographic mode I just get solid colors...

I suppose I could just use a plane and texture it with a sky, but in the long run, that will be kind of a hassle to do every time for every flick screen that I am making.

Here's an example of a render from *Oddworld: Abe's Oddysee*, which is the closest that I am going for: [image]

How can I achieve a sky like this one in orthographic mode?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you be able to set "Transparent" on and then add the background in via the compositor? (See set up below).

[image: nodes]

[image: result]

[image: transparency]

Comment: I suppose that's what I'll have to do! Hopefully it doesn't look too unnatural. If I turn on "transparent" it still saves all of my lighting settings from the Dynamic Sky, right?

Thank you for the help, it's much appreciated!